# Unable to echo variable value

Tags: shell, unix, aix

Assigning the output of sed command in a variable but unable to print its value, the command works fine:-

```
uptime | sed -e 's/^.*up //' -e 's/[^0-9:].*//' | sed 's/:/*60+/g'
```

but I assigned a variable for its out like below:-

```
abc=uptime | sed -e 's/^.*up //' -e 's/[^0-9:].*//' | sed 's/:/*60+/g'
```

and calling variable is not pulling the value.

Tried like below:-

```
echo {"$abc"}
printf "$abc"
echo "${abc}"
```

Kindly suggest the syntax for output.

```
abc=uptime | sed -e 's/^.*up //' -e 's/[^0-9:].*//' | sed 's/:/*60+/g'
```

Actually we need to pull the uptime value for only number of days on AIX server and call that value to form a report of servers which will show number of days server uptime for AIX servers. Need to know how to call the variable value and embedd it in a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your shell, but for most sh-ish variants:

```
abc=$(uptime | sed -e 's/^.*up //' -e 's/[^0-9:].*//' | sed 's/:/*60+/g')
```

Comment: shell that I have on server /usr/bin/ksh

Comment: It'll work with ksh or bash, probably a bunch of others.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not storing the final evaluation in abc.
Try 
`abc=$(uptime | sed -e 's/^.*up //' -e 's/[^0-9:].*//' | sed 's/:/*60+/g')`